# Wave offering; What exactly was the point?

Tags: leviticus

In Leviticus 7 verse 30, This passage is written:

> 30 With their own hands they are to present the food offering to the LORD; they are to bring the fat, together with the breast, and wave the breast before the LORD as a wave offering.

On this passage, did they really wave the sacrifice before offering it? and what exactly was the point in waving it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the other references to the same action (see [here](http://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=wave+offering&qs_version=NASB)), it *would* appear that part of one (or more) of the sacrifices was to be held high and displayed before the gathered and before God that the offering was being made.

If you read further in the [Leviticus](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%207:30-33&version=NASB) passage, you get to this:

> but the breast shall belong to Aaron and his sons

As the breast was the portion "waved" before the Lord, it appears that it was to be a public showing of what had been brought, and after it had been consecrated it was to be given to the Aaronic priests for their use.

Answer (score 0):

The following is regarding Leviticus 7:30.  I hope it's useful.  The source is:
http://www.bibletools.org

The breast named here is what we call the brisket. In the ritual, it was waved before God by means of the offerer holding the brisket in his hands and the priest then laying his hands on the offerer's hands. The offerer then advanced toward the altar by himself as though he was presenting his gift to God. Upon reaching the altar, he returned to the priest with the brisket and handed it to him, signifying God giving that portion of the offering to the priest and his sons.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)